# Change the comment vote rate limiting message in android app

Tags: feature-request, android-app, wording

This is the message you get when you try to vote comments more than once in fifteen seconds, in the android app:

> A vote of comment can only be submitted every 15 seconds

Shouldn't it be:

> A comment vote can only be submitted every fifteen seconds.

**OR**

> You can only submit a comment vote every fifteen seconds

?

Comment: When did it get changed to 15 seconds?  I thought it was 5?

Comment: Not on the Android app it ain't.

Comment: I'm already glad there's no pluralization bug for "seconds". I guess we can't ask for much more than that. :)

Comment: @JeffreyLin missed the android-app tag, but haven't used it so I wouldn't have known otherwise.  Thanks

Comment: @psubsee2003 yup, that's one of the rare cases when adding the tag to the title is useful.